# Atualizar página automaticamente ao acessar o sistema

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo um projeto, onde necessito que ao usuário acessar o sistema, o sistema atualize a página automaticamente, apenas uma vez.
Eu encontrei como fazer isso de tempo em tempo( 5 em 5 segundos, por exemplo), mas necessito que atualize apenas uma vez.

Para atualizar de 5 em 5 segundos, estou utilizando esse código em meu controller:

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5");
```

Existe alguma forma de adaptar para atualizar apenas 1 vez?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com um HTTP header acho difícil, porem você pode usar um *script* na sua pagina:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#updateOnce';
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto não implica que a página se actualize de 5 em 5 segundos, dada a execução do `setTimeout()`?

Comment: não, pois a condição !window.location.hash só será satisfeita uma vez.

Comment: Era isto mesmo que eu precisava.
Apenas alterei o tempo para 1 segundo, isso me trará algum tipo de problema, caso a página demore a carregar no cliente, ou só atualiza após carregar por completo?

Comment: Neste caso só irá atualizar 1 segundo depois da pagina carregar por completo.